# Traffic Statistics per VLAN

Tags: vlan, huawei, traffic, statistics

I'm using Huawei s6720 and I would like to monitor traffic per vlan, example:

```
# 
Interface GigabitEthernet0/0/6 
port link-type trunk 
port trunk allow-pass vlan 200 300 400 500 
#
```

I can verify the traffic on interface, however I don't know the traffic on VLANs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you have layer-3 VLAN interfaces (SVIs) where you can monitor this?

Comment: No, is there anyway for monitoring each VLAN traffic? SNMP? TOP-N? RMON?

Comment: There must be a layer-3 interface for each VLAN somewhere. That is the only way that traffic can get from one VLAN to another VLAN. It must travel through layer-3.

Comment: Yes, VLAN 200 for example. VLAN 300 I'm just passing through but dont have access to the device that make L3. VLAN 400 is just access.